# Keeping menu item highlighted with dynamic changing url id's

Tags: javascript, php, dynamic, selected

http://www.tischabelow.com/images.php#currentExhibition=FREDDY

I would like to keep the menu items on the right (MICHAEL THIBAULT and FREDDY) highlighted pink when they are selected. The image gallery deals with unique page id's, and this is problematic because the url changes with every click of an image. Does anyone know how I would implement this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this function, it will highlight the clicked one and reset the remaining links as white

```
$('.menuitem').on('click',function()
  {
    $('.menuitem').css('color','#FFF');
    $(this).css('color','#ff5ddf')
});
```

Comment: That's great, it worked! However, the remaining links are not retaining their hover class once a menuitem has been clicked.

Comment: I just added !important to the hover class and it worked out. Thanks again!